# go-generics : convert list of objects implements client.Object to a list

Tags: go, generics, polymorphism, kubernetes-go-client

We have the following type which is generic resource list,
the struct has 4 generic parameters (all related to the object list pointer type) but I couldn't find a way to **reduce it**.

```
import(
  ...
   "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"
) 

type GenResourceLister[OBJ any, OBJPTR interface {
    client.Object
    *OBJ
}, LIST interface {
    GetItems() []OBJ
}, LISTPTR interface {
    client.ObjectList
    *LIST
}] struct{}
```

The following function has 2 generic parameters, one of them is the element type of a slice parameter, but I think the other one (its pointer type) **prevents the type inference so the parameters have to be specified on each call. I couldn't find a way to get rid of either of them.**

```
// itemsToObjectList converts a list of objects whose pointer
// type implements client.Object to a list of client.Object

func itemsToObjectList[T any, TPTR interface {
    client.Object
    *T
}](items []T) []client.Object {
    objs := make([]client.Object, 0, len(items))
    for _, resource := range items {
        resource := resource
        objs = append(objs, TPTR(&resource))
    }
    return objs
}




func (l *GenResourceLister[OBJ, OBJPTR, LIST, LISTPTR]) ListResources(
    context context.Context, 
    cli client.Client, 
    listOptions *client.ListOptions
) ([]client.Object, error) {
    resources := new(LIST)
    if err := cli.List(context, LISTPTR(resources), listOptions); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    items := (*resources).GetItems()
    return itemsToObjectList[OBJ, OBJPTR](items), nil
}
```

Btw,
The code is working, we just want to make it simpler and clearer...

Comment: Is it just me, or is that first type declaration unreadable? That should already tell you something isn't right with your approach.

Comment: @jub0bs - so how would you do it better ? this is what I try to resolve :) to make it simple and more clear as the code working as expected .

Comment: The first step would be to avoid anonymous interface types and declare a type for each, in order to see things more clearly.

Comment: @jub0bs - can you please provide an example ?